# Is there a way to create a virtual machine in Microsoft Azure using a Java Program?

Tags: java, api, azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am working on a project which requires to create  a VM in azure. I have worked on AWS where I can use the AWS api to programatically create a VM in AWS. Can I do the same on Azure?

Comment: Did you try Googling it? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing related to creation of virtual machine. i have gone through the blob creation... etc

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157206

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can programmatically create VMs in Windows Azure by consuming [`Windows Service Management REST API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx). I wrote a blog post some days ago about consuming this API using Java which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/08/25/consuming-windows-azure-service-management-api-in-java/. You just have to write code for consuming appropriate operations available in Service Management API.

Comment: Note that in 2014 the Windows Azure team will hopefully be able to offer a better Java experience for service management as we expand the Windows Azure Management Libraries (WAML) to more platforms. We hope to ship our own REST wrappers for these APIs.

Comment: As Jeff pointed out, we're in the final stages of preparing the Azure Java SDK with service management capabilities. The release of this preview SDK is coming very soon. Once we release the SDK I'll post another comment with links to the SDK.

Comment: @bradygaster : Do you have some news about the SDK ?

Answer (score 1):

My team has recently put out some major updates to the [Java SDK](https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-java) and what's available in service management areas in our 0.6.0 release. You can check out the README in our repository to see a detailed of what all the SDK can do, and [this post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/) provides some guidance on getting started with the service management SDK using Maven and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you can programmatically create virtual machines in Azure using
  [Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java).
- But you need to configure your java program as an application in
  Azure portal.
- Check this link for authenticating a java program in
  [azure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md).
- Here is a sample piece of code from Azure SDK for creating a Linux
  virtual

```
VirtualMachine linuxVM = azure.virtualMachines().define("myLinuxVM")
.withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
.withNewResourceGroup("myResourceGroup")
.withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
.withPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()
.withNewPrimaryPublicIpAddress("mylinuxvmdns")
.withPopularLinuxImage(KnownLinuxVirtualMachineImage.UBUNTU_SERVER_16_04_LTS)
.withRootUserName("tirekicker")
.withSsh(sshKey)
.withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_D3_V2)
.create();
```